# Suppress Java warnings

Tags: macos, security, java, firefox

I'm using a website with a Java plugin (applet I think) that prompts me everytime I use it to access the local file system.

These are the two pop ups:

[image: Security Warning 1]

and:

[image: Security warning 2]

I already have the site in question set up as a security exception in my Java settings

This is on Mac OSX 10.9.4 with Firefox 31.

**Is there any way to suppress these popups permanently?** I'm getting them many times a day.

Quick edit to add: If there is some sort of scripting technique to catch the message and kill them, that would be an option I'd consider too.

Comment: The best fix would be to get whoever hosts the application to fix the SSL certificates! I assume you've added a certificate exception to Firefox aswell as Java? (it would have prompted you when you tried to access the site with the expired cert)

Comment: That would be the *logical* way of handling it, yes, but I get the feeling it would require a strong business case, thirtyfive approvers, and signatures in blood. Yes, FF prompted for the certificate, and the exceptions are present

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when it could be set up in Firefox, but in Safari you can open Preferences->Security->Manage Website Settings... In opened window select java, then select your website and in drop down list select "Run in Unsafe Mode". You will see warning icon at near the text. See screenshot from my Safari [image]